# Is it possible to customize or change the android app uninstall message?

Tags: android, android-intent, customization

In my android app, I am uninstalling an app using this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:com.ubercab"));
startActivity(intent);
```

While it works correctly, is it possible to change the message "Do you want to uninstall the app?" to something custom?

I can have another dialog before this uninstall but I just wanted to know if this text can be customized.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't customize the uninstall message.

As you can see in the [UninstallerActivity](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_packageinstaller/blob/marshmallow-release/src/com/android/packageinstaller/UninstallerActivity.java#L81-L89) of the PackageInstaller the message is taken from the resources of the app and it's not customizable:

```
UserManager userManager = UserManager.get(getActivity());
if (dialogInfo.allUsers && userManager.getUserCount() >= 2) {
    messageBuilder.append(getString(R.string.uninstall_application_text_all_users));
} else if (!dialogInfo.user.equals(android.os.Process.myUserHandle())) {
    UserInfo userInfo = userManager.getUserInfo(dialogInfo.user.getIdentifier());
    messageBuilder.append(
            getString(R.string.uninstall_application_text_user, userInfo.name));
} else {
    messageBuilder.append(getString(R.string.uninstall_application_text));
}
```

These are the strings available in the `string.xml`:

```
<string name="uninstall_application_text">Do you want to uninstall this app?</string>
<string name="uninstall_application_text_all_users">Do you want to uninstall this app for <b>all</b> users?  The application and its data will be removed from <b>all</b> users on the device.</string>
<string name="uninstall_application_text_user">Do you want to uninstall this app for the user <xliff:g id="username">%1$s</xliff:g>?</string>
```

Comment: Going by what you said, it should be editable if the app is my own app and I can set the value for the strings?

Comment: Yes, if you create your version of Package Installer you can customize the strings

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot change the text presented by third-party code, including system dialogs like this.